# How to determine real format of an XLSX Excel file?

Tags: excel, format, warnings, detection

I have a well known problem that is described in [Extension Warning On Opening Excel Workbook from a Web Site](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsofficedeveloper/archive/2008/03/11/excel-2007-extension-warning.aspx) microsoft blog entry. I've added URL rewrite to have URL nicely formatted and my mime type matches exactly XLSX recommended file type. However I still get a warning. I suspect that service that provides me those xlsx files mismatches real file format and extension.

Is there a way to determine real xlsx file format? Something that would say what is the native extension for particular Excel file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not find an answer for that anyway. 
However I've discovered the reason why I get a warning from Excel - any parameter in query string will trigger such a warning, even for static files:

> http://localhost/1.xls

works ok

> http://localhost/1.xls?testparam=paramvalue

gives a warning.

Will use URL rewrite to encode parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried changing the mime header from `vnd:excel` to `octet-stream`?  This will still bring Excel up, albeit not embedded into IE, which `vnd:excel` does (but I hate `vnd:excel` anyways because embedding the spreadsheet into the browser screws up the form flow of my web apps).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My excel file already opens as a separate app. I just need to get rid of the warning on some PCs.